# Научить телеграм бота загружать документы на комп

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго всем времени суток.
Я в разработке ботов начинающий, как и в программировании на Python. Столкнулся с проблемой использования библиотеки telepot.

Весь бот на нее завязан, все вроде работает, но функция загрузки файла ботом на компьютер не хочет никак встать. Перепробовал столько вариантов, что стыдно показывать.
Если кто-то реализовал эту функцию у бота, буду благодарен за любую помощь.
Python 3,9 32bit.
Пысы, пользовался и родными мануалами от telepot-a, но что-то так и не разобрался.

Comment: Добавили бы свою попытку в виде минимального примера бота, так проще помогать тем, кто захочет :)

Comment: Мб вы имели ввиду библиотеку pytelegrambotAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку `requests`

```py
import requests

file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id) 
# Я использую библиотеку PyTelegramBotAPI, и там узнать file_id вот так
# в вашем случае вам нужно узнать как в библиотеке вашей узнать и заменить
file = requests.get(
        f'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{API_TOKEN}/{file_info.file_path}')
open(message.document.file_name, 'wb').write(file.content)
```

Comment: Кст, а если так скачивать https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/56fbf491bc841d51d859591d7539aca7bf8b984d/examples/download_file_example.py#L10?

Comment: тоже как вариант, но я не помню можно ли скачивать все файлы или там может быть ограничение до 20МБ, к примеру. У меня кейс был до 10 МБ, мне этот вариант помог)

Comment: В API ограничение на загрузку файлов, а про скачивание не указано. Например, фотки не более 10МБ: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto